# Cannot render all customized fields from my model and queryobject with Djangotables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using djangotables2 for showing my tables in django. I dont wanna show a model itself but something more complicated: a query object, with annotates and counts and more aggregate functions. However when the table is rendered, it shows just the fields of the model and not the fields of my query object. Well, also my model has new attributes so it is not a basic model. Don't know how to fix that.

// view //

```
serial_number_list = TestSerialNumber.objects.filter(test_pool=test_pool).annotate(test_runs=Count('testrun')).order_by(o)
table = TestSerialNumberTable(serial_number_list)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
```

// models.py //

```
class TestSerialNumber(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.ForeignKey("core.SerialNumber", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    test_pool = models.ForeignKey("TestPool", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial_number.serial_number

    def status(self):
        try:
            test_result = self.testresult_set.latest('report')
        except TestResult.DoesNotExist:
            return 'unknown'
        else:
            return test_result.test_status.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ats2_serialnumber'
```

// tables.py //

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from ats2.models import TestSerialNumber

class TestSerialNumberTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta(object):
        model = TestSerialNumber
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#populating-a-table-with-data), you need to add those fields (which aren't in models but added in queryset) in table class:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from ats2.models import TestSerialNumber

class TestSerialNumberTable(tables.Table):
    test_runs= tables.Column() 

    class Meta(object):
        model = TestSerialNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also, i have tested and its working..

url(r'^index_function_view/', index_function_view, name='index_function_view'),

```
__author__ = 'ranvijay'

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2_reports.config import RequestConfigReport as RequestConfig
from django_tables2_reports.tables import TableReport
from django_tables2_reports.utils import create_report_http_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from test_app.models import Person

class PersonTable(TableReport, tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ("id", "name", "active")
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

def index_function_view(request):
    objs = Person.objects.filter(active=True)
    table = PersonTable(objs)
    table_to_report = RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    if table_to_report:
        return create_report_http_response(table_to_report, request)
    return render_to_response('person_list.html',
                              {'table': table},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```